# PHP File upload external url

Tags: php, forms, url, submit, external

I have build a form in which you can add images. Unfortunatelly, I am not able to call "move_uploaded_file" in PHP, as the server is running PHP safe mode and there is no way to modify this (I have checked). Therefore, I submit my form to my OWN server, which handles the file uploading.

On my own server, the file however; is not found. I think it has to do with the form calling the external url.
I know this because

```
echo $_FILES['uploadFile']['name'] ."<br>";
```

returns just an empty line.

The form itself is:

```
<form action="http://ejw.patrickh.nl/load.php" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit ="return checkInput();"> </form>
```

and contains several input buttons.

Bottomline: the form on my own server submits the file perfectly, however when I make use of the form which is on another site, with the above action; no file is found.

Can this be fixed, and if so; how?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: does error reporting is turned on..?

Comment: It is on, however; there are no errors or warnings in both cases.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit , its little confusing , are you trying to implement an intermediate form from which you are going to move the file to actual server .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `method="post"` to submit files.

Also the `enctype` attribute alone can be used only, if `method="post"`.

Comment: Wow, that was really stupid of me. I used the get parameter in order to debug, but wow... Thanks a bunch!